# What does ISTQB say about product testability and maintenance of automated tests in general?

Tags: automated-testing, testability, istqb

ISO 9126 has a subchapter under maintainability that is called testability. In short: "The capability of the software product to enable modified software to be validated". As our department uses ISTQB to describe the way how we should test, I am searching for what ISTQB tells us about this subject.

The context: My project fails to prioritize defect fixes that are not a big issue in the live environment but support our automated test. Due to such a defect a large part of our automated regression test is now failing and the responsible owner need to be convinced that this actually decrease the value of our product. Next to my own common sense, I want to be backed up by the method we are using and have all agreed upon to follow.

Comment: Don't remember what the ISTQB says about this, but: from my personal experience I'm sure you won't succeed with slapping managers with some standard documents. How about this: maybe your project agreed on some testing or quality goals (coverage in some way?). You could argue that you won't be able to meet these goals without the bug fixes. In general: provide your expectations of quality loss to the project decision makers and have them accept this or get you the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

The CTFL material deals with only that part when the people think that the automation is the silver bullet. This topic is dealt together with the testing tools where the same attitude can be experienced.

The CTAL-TTA deals with the automation part. There is a book about it written by Rex Black.

Please, keep in mind that I have read these books a year ago and since than a few things happened. So, please go to the ISTQB website and download the syllabuses and check whether I was right or not.